# Interact with Web Page from java

Tags: java, android, html, apache, http-post

So I'm making a program for android that tries to download something from www.wupload.com. What I want isn't a browser but to interact with the webpage without actually showing it. Like how HtmlUnit is supposed to work.

I'm using apache for the html requests and what I've done so far is send a post that simulates clicking on slow download on the web page. Then I read the response so I can get some variables needed to make the next post and execute the next post. In theory, the web page should be showing the captcha cause the response I get is please enter the captcha, but no image url.

The next step would be to enter the captcha and finally download the file, the problem I'm having is I don't know how to show the captcha image to the user. Do I have to capture it somehow? I know how to make the post to send what the user would type, but the image url of the captcha isn't in the source code.

I thought of inspecting the web page so I could get the url from the DOM tree, like what inspect element on google chrome does, but I have no idea if it's even possible. Any ideas would be great.

thx

Comment: A fairly broad question. Did you try anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The captcha is probably generated using JavaScript. Therefore when you get the source of the website, the captcha hasn't yet been generated and you won't see the image in the source HTML. You would need to run the Javascript somehow. You could try using a WebView because it has built-in support for Javascript, or get a Javascript library for Java and use it somehow. I think it would be **a lot** of work.

Edit:
Actually, if they are using a thirdy-party captcha library, I'm sure it uses some sort of HTTP request system, so you might be able to inspect it with [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) plugin for Firefox.

Comment: Great, used that plugin to see how the http post was made and used it on my own code. Used the response and it gave the challenge of the captcha and the url where the image is supposed to be, then I just used that url to show it on the screen. Thx! :)